# Connecting from websocket client to server

Tags: c#, websocket, client

I have implemented web socket server using web API and Microsoft.WebSockets package.

```
public class MyWSHandler : Microsoft.Web.WebSockets.WebSocketHandler
{

    public string _username;

    public MyWSHandler(string username)
    {
        _username = username;
    }
    public override void OnOpen()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("Socket Opened!");
        if (!Module._clients.Any(x => ((MyWSHandler)x)._username == this._username)) {
                    Module._clients.Add(this);
        }   
        Module._clients.Broadcast("User "+this._username+" has connected!");
    } 
}
```

I can connect to the server from JavaScript client code. Then, I try to connect to the server from a desktop application using System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketClient class with C#.

```
    try
    {
      var websocket = new ClientWebSocket();
      await websocket.ConnectAsync(new Uri(@"ws://localhost:5587/api/ws?username=admin"), CancellationToken.None);
      await Task.WhenAll(Receive(websocket), Send(websocket));
    }
catch(Exception ex){
      Console.WriteLine("Exception: {0}", ex);
}
```

However, the remote server throws an error (404). Is there anything I missed?